# Is payer's PayPal country guaranteed?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

After a payment is approved by the payer, I [load the payment details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get) and obtain the country of the payer from `[payment_response].payer.payer_info.country_code`.

My question: is it guaranteed that the payer's country is always set after the payment was approved? Is it possible for the payer to hide his country? Are there cases, where the payer's country won't be set after the payment approval?

It seems like the payer's country is always set but the PayPal's REST API documentation does not explicitly confirm this.

I hope someone from PayPal will read this since they use StackOverflow in their developer's support page.

I'm asking because I need to conform to EU regulation 1042/2013 which requires me to obtain two non-exclusive proofs of country of origin for each payment I receive. If I knew that payer's PayPal country is not always set, I would have to implement another solution.